# Change js file in production mode

Tags: javascript, cache, production-mode

I changed this file

```
app/design/frontend/VENDOR/THEME/web/mage/validation.js
```

But changes are not reflected; I'm in production mode

I deployed static content with

```
bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f fr_FR
```

cleared the cache

```
php bin/magento cache:flush
php bin/magento cache:clear
```

But changes didn't get applied.
Should i change mode to developer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try to follow this steps(Ubuntu or Linux only) :-**

```
sudo rm -rf pub/static/frontend/ pub/static/adminhtml/ pub/static/_requirejs pub/static/deployed_version.txt var/cache var/page_cache var/generation var/view_preprocessed var/session generated/code  

sudo php bin/magento setup:upgrade  

sudo php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy fr_FR -f 

sudo php bin/magento cache:flush
```

Comment: The js is updated, but I got this message rm: cannot remove ‘var/cache’: Directory not empty
rm: cannot remove ‘generated/code/Magento’: Directory not empty

Comment: are you using linux or ubuntu ??

Comment: The server is Centos, which is managed by WHM cpanel

Comment: not worry about this..

Comment: its just delete command for cache and static files

Comment: if answer useful than approve answer for other pepole ,, :)